# How to avoid Eclipse blocking keyboard shortcuts

Tags: eclipse

I installed a plugin that allowed me to create UML diagram from my code. Everything was working fine until I found that now all keyboard shortcuts (like CTRL-X, CTRL-Z, CTRL-SPACE, CTRL-SHIFT-F,..) except for CTRL-C and CTRL-V now require a click on a small square that appear on the bottom right corner. And this is required every single time.

This are few examples of the square that appears:

[image][image][image]

If I click on the message or press Enter I can access the functionality. Does anyone know how to get rid of this annoying thing or at least reset Eclipse related configurations?
Thanks in advance

EDIT:
I obviously tried uninstalling the plugin but nothing changed.

Comment: Just thinking aloud here... you installed the plugin, and then saw the symptom of the "square" intercepting your shortcuts.  And then you uninstalled the plugin.  It sounds like when you uninstalled, not everything was uninstalled.  You could try poking around in your plugins directory and see what's in there -- maybe search by date?  And what's the name of the plugin?

Comment: The plugin was ObjectAid UML Explorer

Comment: I also remember having used a custom version of Eclipse that had a UML feature built in; I don't remember it's name (in searching if I can find it again), all I remember is that it had a 1-day free trial and it's icon and interface appearance was the same as Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Try `Window / Reset Perspective` as the duplicate shortcuts may be still in the perspective.

Also try restart specifying `-clean` option to rebuild the workspace metadata.

Comment: Could you please specify where I have to add `-clean`?

Comment: -clean goes on the command used to start Eclipse or you can add it to the eclipse.ini file

Answer (score 1):

The pop-ups you are seeing are the "keybinding conflict" popups. These are common when you have two different plugins defining the same keybinding and looks like [these](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/rmc/v7r5m0/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/images/keys3.png). Still in your case there's only one option to choose from and it definitely looks like a bug.

In the Eclipse bugtracker database there are two issues that are looking like the one you have: [#377048](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=377048) and [#374942](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=374942).

These issues are marked as fixed in 4.2-I20120410-0633. So if you are having Eclipse 4.2 without any service releases installed, you would probably have this. The solution is - to use a newer Eclipse version. Eclipse 4.3.1 is [available to download](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) since today, and it should contain a lot of other fixes since 4.2. So I encourage you to install it.

The other solution could be to try playing with keybinding dialog (Window->Preferences->General->Keys) and trying to unbind and re-bind the commands that you are having issues with.